# how to write a single paragraph from multiple paragraphs to a file in java

Tags: java

**for example i have three paragraphs below and i just want  the first paragraph**

> What is the prompt I have been given? If you are writing a paragraph as a response or answer to a particular prompt, such as "You have decided to donate money to charity. Which charity do you choose and why?" or "Describe your favorite day of the week," you will need to think carefully about that prompt and make sure you are directly addressing it, rather than going off topic.
>
> What are the main ideas or issues that I need to address? Think about the topic you are being asked or have decided to write about and consider what the most relevant ideas or issues relating to that topic are. As paragraphs are usually relatively short, it is important that you try to hit on all of the main ideas, without going off topic.
>
> Who am I writing for? Think about who the intended readership of this paragraph or paper is going to be. What is their prior knowledge? Are they familiar with the topic at hand, or will it require a number of explanatory sentences?

my current code

```
try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("F:\\JavaCodeforID\\test.txt"));
        while((sCurrentLine = br.readLine())!= null )
        {

            if(sCurrentLine.contains("MSH"))
            {
                ID =    StringUtils.splitPreserveAllTokens(sCurrentLine,'|');
                controlID = ID[9];
                superID = ID[9];
                if(!uniqueID.contains(controlID)){
                uniqueID.add(controlID);


                File file = new File("F:/JavaCodeforID/out.txt");


                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsolutePath(),true);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
                bw.write(sCurrentLine+"\n");
                bw.close();

                }

            }

        } 


    }
```

Comment: What is your current code?

Comment: i want to write from current line to the last line of a paragraph